# Switch statement / conditional in map function JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using react and am trying to map over an array and create objects:

```
var levels = this.props.levels.map((level, i) =>
  <img key={i} src={levelImg} className={styles.level} />
);
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
var levels = this.props.levels.map((level, i) =>
  switch (i) {
    case 1:
      // do something
      break;
    case 2:
      // do something
      break;
    case 3:
      // do something
      break;
  }
  // ...
  <img key={i} src={levelImg} className={styles.level} />
);
```

I'm getting a syntax error when I try something like that.

Answer (score 19):

In order to use *statements* inside an arrow function, you have to delimit the function body by braces (`{}`) and `return` a value, just like you would do with "normal" function definitions:

```
var levels = this.props.levels.map((level, i) => {
  switch (i) {
    case 1:
      // do something
      break;
    case 2:
      // do something
      break;
    case 3:
      // do something
      break;
  }
  // ...
  return <img key={i} src={levelImg} className={styles.level} />;
});
```

[See the MDN documentation for more information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Can't we return the value in each case? I tried returning values and it warned me `Arrow function expected a return value array-callback-return` but this solution worked without warnings

Comment: @DimuthRuwantha: You can. I guess the warning comes from the fact that the linter cannot know whether the input will always match one of the cases. If there is no `default` clause then it has to assume that the value might match, and if you have no return statement after the `switch` case then the function wouldn't return anything.

Comment: I missed to use a return in default case. it was the issue. once I used a return value in default, warning disappeared.